# postgres how to escape $$ in a do block

Tags: postgresql

Trying to schedule pgpartman maintenance job via postgres cron, I want to do this in a rerunable piece do code so doing it in do block as below.

```
do $$
declare
   schemaname text := 'mytest';
begin
    execute 'set search_path to ' || schemaname||', public';
    if not exists (select * from cron.job where command like '%call run_maintenance_proc%') then 
        select cron.schedule('@daily',$$call run_maintenance_proc()$$);
        raise notice 'sqltext - %', sqltext;
        execute sqltext;
    end if;
end;
$$;
```

But it throws error

```
postgres=> do $$
postgres$> declare
postgres$>    schemaname text := 'nmtest';
postgres$>    sqltext text;
postgres$> begin
postgres$>     execute 'set search_path to ' || schemaname||', public';
postgres$>     if not exists (select * from cron.job where command like '%call run_maintenance_proc%') then
postgres$> select cron.schedule('@daily',$$call run_maintenance_proc()$$);
postgres$>     raise notice 'sqltext - %', sqltext;
postgres$>     execute sqltext;
postgres$>     end if;
postgres$> end;
postgres$> $$;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "call"
LINE 8: select cron.schedule('@daily',$$call run_maintenance_proc()$...
                                        ^
```

```
-- works fine as regular call
postgres=> select cron.schedule('@daily', $$call partman.run_maintenance_proc()$$);
 schedule
----------
        4
(1 row)
```

Just running the cron.schedule outside of the do block works fine, looks like $$ in the cron.schedule is causing the error, probably considering it as end of do block. How to escape $$ of the cron.schedule call? Or any other way to execute?

Comment: You can use `$label$ ... $label` for nested `$$` strings (or outers too). I'm not sure you need `$$` strings here though, I think single quotes should work. You also have an extra `'` on that same line.

Comment: thanks @Marth `$label$` helped, the extra quote was typo removed it.

Comment: Read [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) *4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants*.